# How to convert sql query output from list of tuples to a list of dicts in python3 where each dict represents a row in a table?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, dictionary, tuples

My code look something like this:

```
query = """ SELECT col1, col2 FROM table WHERE col3 = value"""
cursor.execute(query)
data = cursor.fetchall()
print(data)
```

the output will be something similar to:

```
[('col1[1][0]', 'col2[1][0]'), ('col1[2][1]', 'col2[2][1]')]
```

but I don't want the output to be like that, I want it to be a list of dicts where
every row represents a dict that includes key and values.

so the output would look like:

```
col1[1][0], col2[1][0]
col1[2][1], col2[2][1]
```

and without single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data =[('A', 1), ('B', 3)]

for a, b in data:  # this unpacks the tuple
    print(a, b)
```

---

```
A 1
B 3
```